# Getting All Paths of List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, algorithm

i have list of dicts like the following

```
arr = [
    {'name': "item1", 'parent': None},
    {'name': "item2", 'parent': None},
    {'name': "item3", 'parent': None},
    {'name': "item4", 'parent': "item1"},
    {'name': "item5", 'parent': "item1"},
    {'name': "item6", 'parent': "item5"}
]
```

and im looking to get the output like the following output

```
item1 -> item4
item1 -> item5 -> item6
item2
item3
```

So, the question is how can i get all paths from that list using python?

many thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [anytree](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @MafMal im trying to do this without using any external package

Comment: These aren't "all paths". These are merely all paths from leaf nodes to a root node (a node without a parent). @MafMal note that this is not a tree, but rather a "forest" (multiple trees).

Comment: Is the order of the paths important?

Answer (score 0):

Try to build something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "item1",
    "children": [
      { "name": "item4" },
      { "name": "item5", "children": [{ "name": "item6" }] }
    ]
  },
  { "name": "item2" },
  { "name": "item3" }
]
```

Then print without newlines until you find no more children in a path.

Then print a new line and go to the next children/path.

Answer (score 0):

First off: Your current data structure is really unsuitable. You are effectively using names as keys for nodes, but not storing nodes in a dictionary that would allow fast access by name. Let's fix that using a quick dict comprehension; we'll build a "parent" dictionary:

```py
parent_by_child = {node['name']: node['parent'] for node in arr}
```

This gives us a convenient mapping from child node name to parent node name (side note: if you want low *guaranteed* constant factors in practice, you'd enumerate nodes and use them as indices into an array / list rather than using a dictionary (hash map)).

Let's also build the set of parents (non-leaves):

```py
parents = set(parent_by_child.values())
```

Now we can just go through all leaves, trace their path until you reach a "root" (a node without parent):

```py
def trace_path(node_name):
    path = []
    while node_name is not None:
        path.append(node_name)
        node_name = parent_by_child[node]
    return reversed(path) # reverse the path to get root -> ... -> child
```

Now we can combine this to go over all leaves and print their paths back to the root:

```py
for node_name in parent_by_child:
    if node_name not in parents:
        print("->".join(trace_path(node_name)))
```

This produces

```
item2
item3
item1->item4
item1->item5->item6
```

This is sorted by the leaves (in the order they appear in `arr`). If you want to get exactly the order in your post (sorted by parents), you could sort the resulting path strings. Or, you could switch to an adjacency-list based format:

```py
children_by_parent = {node['name']: [] for node in arr}
for node in arr:
    if node['parent'] is not None:
        children_by_parent[node['parent']].append(node['name'])
path = []
def print_paths(node):
    path.append(node)
    if children_by_parent[node]: # parent
        for child in children_by_parent[node]:
            print_paths(child)
    else: # leaf
        print("->".join(path))
    path.pop()

for node in arr:
    if node['parent'] is None: # only consider roots
        print_paths(node['name'])
```

This prints everything in the desired order:

```
item1->item4
item1->item5->item6
item2
item3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear. Here's my interpretation:

```py
graph = {}
for edge in arr:
    graph.setdefault(edge["parent"], set()).add(edge["name"])

paths = []
for root in graph[None]:
    stack = [[root]]
    while stack:
        path = stack.pop()
        if path[-1] in graph:
            for node in graph[path[-1]]:
                if node not in path:
                    stack.append(path + [node])
                else:
                    paths.append(path)
        else:
            paths.append(path)
```

First built a little `graph`:

```py
{None: {'item3', 'item2', 'item1'},
 'item1': {'item4', 'item5'},
 'item5': {'item6'}}
```

And then fetch all `paths` starting with roots (collected in `graph[None]`) with unique nodes and ending at a leaf with a depth first walk through the graph:

```py
[['item3'],
 ['item2'],
 ['item1', 'item5', 'item6'],
 ['item1', 'item4']]
```